# Open a link(blog) with categories in Magento

Tags: rwd, magento-1.9, blog

I created a category with the name blog, now I want to open my Wordpress blog(Fishpig Wordpress extension) in Magento shop.

I tried to change the category url to the Wordpress blog url but it will just open a blank site instead of my blog.

**I want:** If I click on the category link , it will open my wordpress blog. What can I do?

Comment: You can use the "external URL" feature of the free FlexCms extension to add arbitrary links to the category tree: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/FireGento_FlexCms

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The descriptions looks very good! But how do I install it manual? I download the zip folder and unzip it and copied it to the installation folder of my other extension - but it seems like nothing happend.

Comment: Ok I already found a solution, ty

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a good way how to solve this problem:

In magento, click on Catalog -> Manage Categories

Click on the root category that you wants to create and click on ‘Add Subcategory’ button

Enter the name of the catagory. e.g. Blog and mark Is Active = Yes

Once created, take note of the ID that is assigned to this category

Click on Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

Find and click on the entry of the category which you have just created.

Set Redirect = permanent (301) and save

Go back to URL Rewrite Management

Create a new entry. Create URL Rewrite = Custom

Type in ID path = any name. e.g. myblog

Request Path = the category ID  which you have just copied

Target Path = the path you want to redirect.

Redirect = Permanent

Save this custom URL rewrite entry and clear your index by going to System -> Index Management -> Select All and click submit (Actions = Reindex Data)

Basically, what we have done so far is to mark category URL rewrite as permanent and then create a new URL rewrite that redirect the system(raw) URL to the one you intended to.

Comment: Hi Helloworld, welcome to Magento SE. Thought the link in your answer resolved your issue, putting that link only in  your answer makes your answer "weak". Your answer will not have any relevance if that link become passive. So please provide a short description about what is that link is talking about and how it is helped you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hello @RajeevKTomy, thank you for the nice comment. You got a good point there. I hope my answer is now more helpfull,